# if #available(iOS 9, *) Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift2, ios9

I have found a line in my code that doesn't like to be run on iOS8, but have a way to perform the same task on iOS8 with different logic, that doesn't like iOS9.

I have used `if #available(iOS 9, *)` to perform the code I need on iOS9 and code on iOS8. However, when running, after a few calls to the function, the iOS9 device runs the code it shouldn't and crashes. Did I miss step in setting up the `if #available(iOS 9, *)`?

The code is below

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    if(self.otherChats[loc].last?.timestamp! != messageObj.timestamp!){
        self.otherChats[loc].append(messageObj)
        self.Notfication.postNotificationName(_Chat.Notification.DidGetMessage, object: nil)
    }
} else {
    self.otherChats[loc].append(messageObj)
    self.Notfication.postNotificationName(_Chat.Notification.DidGetMessage, object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   let systemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion        
    if((Double)(systemVersion) > 9.0)
    {
        if(self.otherChats[loc].last?.timestamp! != messageObj.timestamp!){
            self.otherChats[loc].append(messageObj)
            self.Notfication.postNotificationName(_Chat.Notification.DidGetMessage, object: nil)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.otherChats[loc].append(messageObj)
        self.Notfication.postNotificationName(_Chat.Notification.DidGetMessage, object: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `available` check should be working. Since the code to be exdcuted is equal in both cases (apart from the `if`), the problem is likely to be that the `if` condition (`self.otherChats[loc].last?.timestamp! != messageObj.timestamp!`) is `true`, when you think it should be `false`.

Try to add logs to both `#available` blocks, and most likely you'll see, that the second block (the iOS 8 one) is never executed on an iOS 9 device.

Comment: if `(self.otherChats[loc].last?.timestamp! != messageObj.timestamp!)` was true or false, it should never run past the `else` since the `else` is linked with  `if #available(iOS 9, *) { `

Comment: @MarkMasterson, that's exactly what I'm trying to say. Are you sure that is was in the `#available` else block? Because the result is the same in both. Did you put log/brakepoint there? If it is, then it's probably a bug, and it's better to report it to Apple via http://bugreport.apple.com.